# undefined symbol when importing pyo

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, portaudio, jack

I am running python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed the python-pyo package, but when I import the pyo module I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pyo.so: undefined symbol: jack_port_register
```

It seems like I must have screwed up the jack libraries on my system somehow, but I can't figure out what is broken.

```
[~/Downloads/pyo-read-only]$ ldconfig -p|grep jack
    libjack.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0
    libjack.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so
[~/Downloads/pyo-read-only]$ objdump -tT /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0|grep jack_port_register
000000000000a3a0 g    DF .text  00000000000001a1  Base        jack_port_register
```

I have tried building python-pyo from scratch but I get the same error. If I build it without --use-jack, I get a segmentation fault when I try to boot a server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It was fixed by ensuring I had the correct packages installed.
From http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/compiling.html

```
sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev libportmidi-dev portaudio19-dev liblo-dev
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev python-dev python-tk
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk python-wxgtk3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a bit further by manually adding -ljack to the setup.py and building from source.